# what is the shortcut for find a usage of XML file in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

As you know there is many useful shortcuts that improve you coding speed.

One of them is **find usage** of Class or Method that works with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. they works on methods and class names but I wonder how I can find a Usage of XML file like Layout Without Search in project and use Find Usage.

Because the name of XML file is not in the file Like classes and I Always search it's name in whole project.
I googled but could not find any answer.

Comment: cntrl+f > findy your key by typing in win

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All keys are given for windows

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for find keywords in a single file

**Can do it like this** 
Find usage of an XML|  <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> after you select the XML layout

[image]

**There is another way**(not sure you gonna like it) .. 
Try to delete a xml and it will not be deleted at the first time.It will show you all the usages of it ask you to confirm you deletion. You can see all the usages at the terminal,so that way you can find them all.

[image]

click on view usages button it will show them all

For any short-key *File -> Settings -> Keymap ->* (you can even Choose Eclipse/Visual Studio short key types in android studio)

**Here are some default short keys for windows**

Format code   | <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Add unimplemented methods   | <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Show logcat | <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>

Build | <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>

Build and Run | <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>

Find | <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Find in project| <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Find and replace | <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Find and replace in project | <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Override methods | <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Show project | <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

Hide project - logcat | <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd>

Collapse all | <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad +</kbd>

View Debug Points | <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>

Expand all | <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad -</kbd>

Open Settings | <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>

Select Target (open current file in Project view)  | <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> → <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Search Everywhere | <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> → <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (Double shift)

Code | Surround With | <kbd>CTRL</kbd> → <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Create method form selected code | <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

Comment: This is nice, but I think you could have just answered the question that was asked.

Comment: nice this is not the answer.

Comment: @Kenji go and find it ,i showed you the path you need to go to keys in android studio :P

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i'm still new to this site i will learn thanks for mentioning those stuff in different posts.It's very helpful  :)

Comment: @Kenji How about my new suggestion?

Comment: @Kenji check my answer

Comment: anyone who down votes this,I have given a solution so if you  have a reason to down vote mention that in a comment

Comment: I upvote you for second answer but rally smart but like to get better answer.

Comment: @Kenji are you looking for the Alt+F7 added that as well to the answer .click on an xml and use that

Comment: I can confirm that Alt+F7 is working. I've added it as answer in the same @Charuka edit the answer. +1 for it.

Answer (score 4):

My personal preference is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. It will display a popup dialog in which you can type the thing that you are searching and it will look in your entire project folder.

Alternately there is already a **Find Usage** feature in xml when you right click it. And it does shows the file that uses it.

[image]

In my example I did find the use of my `analytics_debug.xml` then a mini console below will show indicating which file uses it. Selecting the file in usage console redirects you to the exact line of code in which the XML is called.

I reproduce this usecase in **Ubuntu 16.04, A.S. version 2.1.1**.

Comment: as I told in question I use to use this but it is not find usages, it just search text.

Answer (score 2):

[From IntelliJ IDEA Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/finding-usages-in-the-current-file.html):

> **Finding Usages in the Current File**
>
> To find usages of a symbol in the current file:
>
> 1. Click the desired symbol in the editor, or in the Structure view.
> 2. On the main menu, choose Edit | Find | Find Usages in File, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. The encountered usage is
>    highlighted in the editor.

But this ***didn't work in Linux***, instead use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Comment: I have tried it using my android studio and same time you pointed that using doc +1 from me for the reference

Comment: it is true but you answered after @user1231 but +1

Answer (score 0):

For **Mac users** the shortcut is

1. > First select the file in project view (⌥ + (fn) + F1)

   [image: select in project view]      hit enter to select 1st option or select [image: select scroll from source]
2. > show usage of file (⌥ + (fn) + F7)

   [image]
   hit enter to open the file